# List<Type1> to List<Type2> conversion WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list, type-conversion

I created simple type that contains only one dependency property "Text" returns string. For easy conversion from string to my type I wrote this code:

```
public static implicit operator string(StringDP sdp)
{
    return sdp.Text;
}

public static implicit operator StringDP(string str)
{
    return new StringDP(str);
}
```

I want to have similar conversion from `List<string>` to `List<myType>`. Am I able to do this? Or I have to use something like this:

```
public List<string> Convert(List<myType> lst);
public List<myType> Convert(List<string> lst);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx):

> Either the type of the argument to be converted, or the type of the result of the conversion, but not both, must be the containing type.

Both of the types involved in your hypothetical implicit conversion are concrete versions of the generic `List<T>` class. Since you can't add operators to the `List<T>` class yourself, and since that's where the `implicit` operators to achieve your goal would have to be, it can't be done.

Without more context, I admit that I can't really comment knowledgeably on the implicit conversion to and from `string` that you've defined. But in general, you should be very careful with `implicit` conversions. Assuming the implicit conversion of your type fits within the "safe" guidelines, then a conversion of a whole list of the type would be "fine".

This conversion can be done with custom methods such as your examples. Or you can use LINQ or the `List<T>.ConvertAll()` method. E.g.:

```
List<string> listOfString = listOfMyType.Select(item => (string)item).ToList();
List<myType> listOfMyType = listOfString.ConvertAll(item => (myType)item);
// etc.
```

However, even there I would suggest that you should be careful about how you are using something like that. It's one thing to convert a single instance of a value, but converting a whole collection involves quite a lot more overhead and most likely is not the correct way to solve the problem.

Not know what the actual problem *is*, I can't offer an alternative. Just to suggest you be very wary of the design path you appear to be headed down.